# Get list of events user is attending on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get list of events my friend / user attends. This info is publicly visible through Facebook pages.

I'm making a request to `/userid/events` but it returns empty array of results, though user does have upcoming events and calling `/me/events` is working. (all is ran in graph explorer)

I couldn't find any documentation about any limitations or required permissions to explain why it's not working e.g. [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/)

Is it a bug? How to workaround it?

Comment: Facebook's API generally forbids accessing information on anyone who hasn't *themselves* authorized your application for a permission (for privacy reasons). **Your** access token can't get **someone else's** events.

Comment: I would guess you need to get your friends' permissions first. Although their information is visible to you on Facebook, it doesn't mean they are public. You may want to create test users to test your program, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: @ceejayoz makes sense, but what's the purpose of `/userid/events` if it doesn't provide any info?

Comment: @JoeyZhang thanks for an answer, but it can't be scaled at all, no workarounds?

Comment: @NGix, I don't think you can bypass the permission check. Accessing event list has to have consent from users, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @NGix It's presumably so you can use a page ID to access the page's events. In that case, this restriction wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/userid/events` with a user who auzhorized your App, but using `/me/events` is recommended. Either way, just because stuff is public on [facebook.com](https://www.facebook.com) does not mean you can get it with the API. You always need to authorize users before you can get any data, for privacy reasons.

In other words: It´s not a bug, there is no workaround, it´s not possible without user authorization.